# Qt Convert UTF16 Hex string to QString

Tags: c++, qt, utf-16, qstring

I want to convert a string in hex and utf16 codec to QString 
for example like what I achieve from this code:

```
QString str1 = QString::fromWCharArray(L"\x0633\x0644\x0627\x0645"); // what I want
```

but when I try the following code every thing went wrong what is the correct way for doing this.

```
QByteArray hex =  QByteArray::fromHex("0633064406270645");
// wrong text in str2 it should be equal to str1
QString str2 = QString::fromUtf16((char16_t*)hex.data());
```

Comment: What if you just do: `QString str2(hex);`?

Comment: Convert str1 to UTF16 QBytearray, use toHex, and compare if you get 0633.

Comment: @wasthishelpful no that does not work at all

Comment: @hyde this str1.toLatin1().toHex(); gives me '3f' but I actually want a way to convert a utf16 hex to QString which is already i think holds 16 bit characters. how could i get the same string as str1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is wrong with this code?

```
QByteArray hex =  QByteArray::fromHex("0633064406270645");
// wrong text in str2 it should be equal to str1
QString str2 = QString::fromUtf16((char16_t*)hex.data());
```

Endian is! This is equivalent of `L"\x3306\x4406\x2706\x4506"` and not of `L"\x0633\x0644\x0627\x0645"`.

So to overcome this problem you can add [BOM](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom1) to string

```
QByteArray hex =  QByteArray::fromHex("FEFF0633064406270645");
QString str2 = QString::fromUtf16((char16_t*)hex.data());
```

Didn't test it but is should resolve problem.

Alternative solution is to flip order of bytes in sigle UTF-16 character  (to change it to little endian).

```
QByteArray hex =  QByteArray::fromHex("3306440627064506");
QString str2 = QString::fromUtf16((char16_t*)hex.data());
```

Comment: oh that is correct I miss this line from the QString::fromUtf16 documentation 'This function checks for a Byte Order Mark (BOM). If it is missing, host byte order is assumed.' thanks you save me time.